# Convert a whole number amount of cents to a readable dollar amount in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

```
var num = 1629; // this represents $16.29
num.toLocaleString("en-US", {style:"currency", currency:"USD"});
// outputs $1,629
```

So far this is as close as I can come. I tried all of the options that toLocaleString provides but there seems to be no easy way to get the outcome I want (which is not as expected). Is there no built-in function that exists in JS?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Try dividing the number of cents by 100 to get the dollar equivalent. I.E.:

```js
const number = 1629;
const dollars = (cents / 100).toLocaleString("en-US", {style:"currency", currency:"USD"});
```

`dollars` now equals "$16.29"

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect for me. I considered doing this but was deterred when researching my question because of some post about float precision that mentioned this function. My mistake.

Comment: I think you need to assign `dollars` to the value of the last line to actually change its assignment.

Comment: Is there a valid reason as to why someone would use `.toLocalString(...)` when they could just do `dollars = '$' + dollars;`?

Comment: Depending on what locale the user is in, the output could vary wildly. For example, the position of the currency symbol, usage of dots vs commas for decimal points and thousands separators, etc (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString#using_locales)

Comment: In this case, the USD currency format in the en-US locale would automatically format `123456.789` dollars to `$123,456.79`, taking care of the position and type of currency symbol, the commas and dots, and rounding to 2 decimal places.

Answer (score 5):

Why not divide through 100 before toLocaleString?

```
var num = 1629; // this represents $16.29
num /= 100; // cent to dollar
num.toLocaleString("en-US", {style:"currency", currency:"USD"});
```